# How do I make GCDAsyncSocket that is declared in AppDelegate available to view controllers

Tags: xcode, ios5, gcdasyncsocket, appdelegate

Following a post of similar question (which doesn't work), I declared a instance of GCDAsyncSocket on AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class GCDAsyncSocket;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    GCDAsyncSocket *asyncSocket;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GCDAsyncSocket *asyncSocket;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

and do the socket initialization in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize asyncSocket;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    self.asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];
    NSString *host = @"10.1.100.50";
    uint16_t port = 3040;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.asyncSocket connectToHost:host onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
    }

    char bytes[] = "run";
    NSData* requestData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
    [self.asyncSocket writeData:requestData withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    return YES;
}
```

The I tried to access the socket from multiple view controllers by invoking:

```
GCDAsyncSocket *asyncSocket = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] asyncSocket];
```

the code completion stops at [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] without being able to suggest asyncSocket.
What should I do to make asyncSocket accessible in multiple view controllers when the instance of asyncSocket is being declared in AppDelegate? Thanks!

Here's my Xcode project file : http://bit.ly/PLe1Le

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. And the application delegate is a great place for a socket connection. I think you're being tripped up by something relatively simple.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns an `id` or generic object pointer to  an object that conforms to the `<UIApplicationDelegate>` protocol. So code completion has no way of knowing that your application's delegate is an instance of *your* `AppDelegate` class.

Remember if you are in fact using an instance of `AppDelegate` to be your application's delegate then `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` will return a pointer to your delegate, but it will be the generic pointer discussed above.

The simplest solution is to cast the  pointer you receive back from `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to be a pointer of `AppDelegate` type.

For example:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// We now have a pointer to your app delegate that the compiler knows is an AppDelegate.
// So code completion will work and it will compile.
GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [myAppDelegate asyncSocket];
```

Or you can stack the calls to one statement. The syntax looks a little funky, but this is how it's done.

```
GCDAsyncSocket *socket = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] asyncSocket];
```